# How to use ActorPublisher to publish message to more than one subsriber

Tags: java, http, websocket, stream, akka

I'm writing a websocket to push msgs to clients.

and when I trying to open two browser tab with same uri
Got error like this:

```
[default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default)] WebSocket handler failed with ActorPublisher only supports one subscriber (which is allowed, see reactive-streams specification, rule 1.12)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActorPublisher only supports one subscriber (which is allowed, see reactive-streams specification, rule 1.12)
```

Comment: Don't use ActorSubscriber. Use BroadcastHub as explained in the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#Using_the_BroadcastHub